# How can I check the origin of a Token?

Tags: smart-contract, token

A smart contract minted a Token and send it to my wallet, after a time has passed how can I check if that smart-contract in specific did mint the token?

Answer (score 1):

the token is present in your wallet as "`<policy-id>.<token-name-hex-ascii>`"

if you want to check only for a specific smart contract (minting policy) to be the one which minted the token just get the hash of the smart contract and compare it to the "`<policy id>`"

#### if the minting policy hash corresponds to the policy id then that's your smart contract

if that is not the case but you still want to know **which** smart contract was used you could do the following:

1. check the transaction that sent you the token
2. if that transaction did not mint the token then that token must have come from somewhere else
3. (go to 1) going back you'll find a transaction that minted the token and in that transaction, the smart contract (minting policy) must be included in order to be executed. here is your smart contract